# Android dagger dependency cycle

Tags: android, dependency-injection, cycle, dagger

I have 2 dependencies with the same Scope that require of each other.

My dependencies are domain services with different methods ( each method a different business case). some business cases might use methods from another domain.

In order to do this I need domain1 to be available for domain2 and vice versa.

but when i do this i get a dependency cycle compilation error. after googling for some time i found that in order to overcome this issue i must inject one of the dependencies with the @Inject annotation instead of a constructor parameter in the  @Module.

when i try this the code compiles but dagger is not injecting the second dependency at all.

is there a way to achieve what i want with Dagger?

Comment: The answer is yes, but without code no one will be able to tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I think there might be a fundamental issue in your dependency structure, can you post some code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Your problem:** AClass has a constructor dependency on BClass, which has a constructor dependency on AClass. Even without Dagger, this wouldn't work: If they depend on each other, which would you create first?

**Your attempted solution:** If you create one of your classes (BClass) using `new`, and it no longer has an `@Inject`-annotated constructor, you could wait until after AClass is constructed to populate your BClass instance. However, if you create an object using `new`, you'll need to inject it by passing it into a members-injection method or `MembersInjector<BClass>` object. You'll also need to make sure that this happens outside of the `@Provides` method (because the whole reason `@Provides` is being called is so you can construct a value to pass into AClass's constructor). This is fragile and fairly ugly.

**My suggestion:** Use [indirection via Provider](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/200). Have AClass inject `Provider<BClass>`, or BClass inject `Provider<AClass>`, or both. As long as you don't call `get` within the constructor, you'll allow Dagger to create AClass and defer the creation of BClass until you need it. You need no additional configuration in order to inject a `Provider<T>` or `Lazy<T>` for any class T you've bound in your Component; see ["Bindings in the Graph" in the User's Guide](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide#bindings-in-the-graph) for the full list of available injections.

Comment: Thanks for your time, this is good information. in the end i decided to add a new  extra layer("Interactor")  between the presentation and domain layers to merge multiple domains into complex Business cases.

Comment: @Jeff can you explain a bit more on how to achieve this

Comment: @WISHY Without specific code I'm not sure how much clearer I can make it: Inject a Provider of the object you're currently injecting directly, as in the link in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I made this possible using dagger.Lazy and Hilt (almost same as dagger - it is using dagger under the hood). But be careful. Circular dependency may be result of bad design and can lead to  many problems. Here is example:

```
class Cls1 @Inject constructor() {
    @Inject lateinit var cls2: dagger.Lazy<Cls2>
}

class Cls2 @Inject constructor() {
    @Inject lateinit var cls1: dagger.Lazy<Cls1>
}

@HiltAndroidApp
class ApplicationClass: Application() {
    @Inject lateinit var cls1: Cls1
    @Inject lateinit var cls2: Cls2

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    }
}
```